# Tax calculation for logged in users

Tags: magento

The issue is the tax is not included on product price to logged in users.

Tax is added to product price correctly to guest users, in cart when shipping country is entered and on final checkout page.

**[[Something I have noted is that the price displays correctly for both non logged in and newly created logged in user. The price will only be displayed without tax once the logged in user has an address (shipping) applied to their account. It appears that Magento is interpreting the taxable country as a country without a tax rule]]**

The store is UK based retail site and should only display products with UK VAT 20% added.

Until recently this worked perfectly. Last week the product price started displaying without tax to logged in users with a shipping country set.

Default Country: UK
Shipping Orign Country: UK
Tax Calculation Based On: Shipping Origin
Default Tax Destination default country: UK
Price Display settings: include tax
Tax rules configured for EU VAT

Any advice on where to look and debug why a logged in user with valid country is resulting in magento showing product without tax.

Configuration screen grabs:-
[image: Manage Tax Rules]
[image: Manage Tax Rates]
[image: Edit Tax Rate]
[image: customer tax groups]
[image: product tax classes]
[image: Customer Groups]
[image: Tax Configuration]

Comment: Which Magento version do you use? Have you installed the extension Mage_Econda?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.4.2.0, No Mage_Econda is not installed... This issue was noticed after an update but with all extensions added disabled and layouts reverted the issue persists.

Comment: I have tested this with a new user with no shipping country set and the tax displays correctly up until a shipping address is saved. The shipping address can have any country, all appear to be interpreted by Magento as having no tax rule allocated. The change in Magento' behaviour seems to be two fold: 1. Changing the on page product price based on shipping country. 2. Not recognizing that the customers shipping country has a tax rule allocated.

Comment: Have you fixed this? I have the same problem on 1.9

Answer (score 2):

- Do your customers with account really have the correct Customer Group (could have changed due to an update)?
- Is this Customer Group really correctly linked to the correct Tax Group?
- Are the products correctly linked to this Tax Group?
- Is it both incorrect in the display of product and in the price of the final order?
- I suggest adding logs and debugging in the tax system to identify where exactly it is going wrong.

I guess it has something to do with the difference in customer group between guest (no customer group) and normal (logged in) customer.

Comment: I will provide feedback from your points. Something I have noted is that the price displays correctly for both non logged in and newly created logged in user. The price will only be displayed without tax once the user has an address (shipping) applied to their account. It appears that Magento is interpreting the taxable country as a country without a tax rule.

Comment: Do your customers with account really have the correct Customer Group (could have changed due to an update)? YES

Comment: Is this Customer Group really correctly linked to the correct Tax Group? YES

Comment: Is it both incorrect in the display of product and in the price of the final order? NO, prices include tax correctly in the basket and final checkout with a shipping address applied, but at the same time product prices show without tax on the product page.

Comment: Hmm, it might be an issue with the product price display template? It can be found in app/design/frontend/<theme-dir>/<theme-dir>/template/catalog/product/price.phtml if I am correct. This contains code for displaying and the product price based on configuration options. Maybe it can be of help.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem obvious, but does your tax rule actually apply to the customer group for logged in customers?

Admin > customers > customer groups 
Admin > sales > tax > manage tax rules

[image: tax rule]
[image: Customer tax classes]

Comment: Hi Sonassi... Thanks but the customer group is assigned a tax group correcty.

Comment: Then without looking at it myself, I'd struggle to explain why its not working as expected. I've never come across this before with 1.4.20, so triple check your tax rules - as that is the only thing I can imagine it being. Have you tested the same scenario on a *clean* 1.4.2.0 installation to see if the issue is in the core?

Comment: Hi Sonassi, I suspect that an extension has created the issue, being as one day it work and the next not. In addition what is very strange is when setting the store to display prices with and without tax both display the without tax. What I really need is a way to debug. Further more is Magento supposed to show the price with the tax as per their shipping country to a logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

Just had this EXACT same problem today, cost me hours off my life.  Here's the solution:

*Configuration* > *Sales* > *Shipping Settings*

Ensure that *Origin* > *Country* is set to the UK

Works like a charm for General and Not logged in customers, or anyone else in the Retail Customer group

Comment: Hi Nero, thanks for this and I am aware of this issue and this is not causing this problem as on all sites this is set to United Kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem....
It turned out to be the logged in user is outside the tax zip/postcode in the specified tax zone so no tax is applied (ie. magento assumes the user is overseas so taxes don't apply)

In the backend click Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Zones and Rates. Edit the tax rate and make sure "Zip/Post is range?" is set to YES.

Lookup you postcode ranges in which that tax rate apples (ie. here is australia the range is from 0800 - 8000 to account for all postcodes in all states and territories). Enter in your ranges.

Save and you are all done :)